# Best way to send scheduled e-mail in an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, triggers, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have an `MVC` application that sends e-mail periodically on a specific times. Although I can manage this on `Debugging` mode by using `Quartz.NET`, it does not working when publishing to `IIS Server` due to the recycling application pool, etc. So, I think there is a general problem regarding to this and I think of `database trigger` or `windows service` to fire the e-mail sending. So, what is the best option for this? Actually if creating a trigger on database side is much more simpler as just running a script, I would prefer this. But if there is a better choice could you please clarify me on how to integrate it to my `MVC` application? 
Note: I use `MSSQL Server 2008` as database and `Windows Server 2008` for publishing the application.

Comment: Just wrap your Quartz code in a windows service.

Comment: How? Could you pls give an example and post as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an application that runs alongside your MVC app that does the email sending. Trigger it using a scheduled task that runs every x minutes or at a set time each day.

Comment: Do you mean to add an application to the Solution? Could you give an example pls?

Comment: Yes. So create a new Console application project in your solution that will be responsible for sending the emails and build. (Create a hello world for the sake of testing, or even just get it to update something in your DB so you know it has run). Browse to the exe that was created in the bin folder and take a copy of the filepath to it. Open Scheduled Tasks, "Create Task..", give it a name, set a trigger (or many) on the Triggers tab, Select the Actions tab and add a "New.." action. Add the previously copied path to the Program/Script field (or browse to it), click ok. That's essentially it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I would prefer to keep my e-mail logic in MVC app instead of moving to another project. So, I need a much more simple modification that does not require changes in the project structure except from config changes. Anyway, voted+ for your suggestion that can also be applied for other scenarios.

Comment: Ok, however, I will advise you to think about separation of concerns. I would keep the MVC app concerned about displaying a website and receiving requests. Getting data for the website, for example, should be split out in to a different project, perhaps using the repository pattern. The MVC app and other apps (task app) could then get their data from the centralised repository. The emailer task is then only concerned about getting data and figuring out who to send emails to; it's not mixed up with code that's designed to display the website. The long game is to minimize spaghetti code and DRY.